# Android: Why to choose lowest version?

Tags: android

I have seen many times that android recommends to choose lower version to create a new android application. why so? or am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are writing app that works from 1.5, then there's no reason for restricting users that actually have this version from using it. They are not gonna download/buy even though their android version is capable of running your app. You would only hurt your pocket.